# Importing shapefiles in folders into geodatabase?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, arcgis-10.3, file-geodatabase

Using ArcGIS Desktop 10.3, I need to import thousands of folders containing shapefiles into a geodatabase. How can I do this?

Here is a part of the files that need to be exported into a geodatabase:
[image]

Comment: Are the shps within each folder uniquely named or are some of them the same?  If same, are you wanting to merge like named layers together?

Comment: It's almost always a mistake to create thousands of tables *anywhere*. The real power of databases is in rows with the same schema, so reducing your table count is a critical step in data import.

Comment: Some of the shapefiles have the same name and need to be kept separated as they represent different area.

Answer (score 2):

Right click your geodatabase, select import feature class (multiple), navigate to folders containing shape files, shift+click all your shapefiles.

If you want to consolidate all the thousands of folders into one, that could make that easier

Comment: How can you consolidate these folders into one?

Comment: just copy and paste all into one

Comment: there is 24000 files, the computer does not have enough power to load so much data.